# Make existing PDF's in to templets - iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, adobe

I am trying to make some existing PDF's into templets.
Because these documents hold real data I am replaceing this data such as names and addrsss and making them into dummy place holders.

Examples

[[Name]]

[[Address1]]

When I alter the text via the iText version 5 library replace via a program I can use the template.
To speed things up I tried to use Adobe DC.
When using this method the template stops working.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you do *via the iText version 5 library* and in particular how; it also is unclear how you *to speed things up you tried to use Adobe DC*.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question;

- you have (or want to have) a template document
- fill in the template with data from a program
- turn this back into a pdf

You can easily achieve some of your goals with iText.
I suggest you look into http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-filling-out-forms